# POST function is not working in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In the below code, the post function is not working. If I put the post function before get function,  then get function stops working. these statements are as same as from a tutorial and there it was working well. I couldn't figure out what was the problem.

```
import webapp2

form = """
 <form method="post">
    What is your birthday
     <br> 
     <input type="text" name="month">
     <input type="text" name="day">
     <input type="text" name="year">    
     <br>
     <input type = "submit">
 </form>
"""

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(form) 

    def post(self):
        self.response.out.write("Thanks")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage)
], debug=True)
```

Here is mine app.yaml file

```
application: start
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

Comment: what is the error? can you provide the error log and your `app.yaml` file?

Comment: i have added my app,yaml file

Comment: does the answer work for you?

Comment: Suraj, your code works for me without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your `app.yaml` file: the [`application`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=en?#application) is an optional element. It is the identifier you selected when you created the application in the Google Cloud Platform Console. You can ignore this while development.

Also the [`threadsafe`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=en?#threadsafe_1) element can either be `true` or `false`, not `yes`. Make your `app.yaml` like this:

```
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

Comment: It's still not working.  I made the same app. Yaml file.  But i couldn't remove the application field.  Because Google app engine starts showing error when I remove that

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue on **Notepad++**, replace `tabs` with `spaces`, I guess it's an `indentation` issue.